# granting permissions in oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I am trying to grant priveledges to a user with

```
CREATE USER Naa IDENTIFIED BY specialgirl; 
GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCES TO Naa; 
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA.PROCEDURE TO Naa;
```

but I am constantly getting `invalid character` error

Comment: Way off-topic for SO; belongs on [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

There is no role like `RESOURCES` in Oracle. it's `RESOURCE`.

```
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE TO naa;
```

The `invalid character` error might be because of, you are trying to `GRANT EXECUTE` on an invalid schema or object name.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON <schema_name>.<object_name> TO naa;
```